# Activation of the app failed

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps

I am developing the UWP application with VS 2017.Sometimes I am getting error

> Activation of the app failed.The operation was not completed because
>   an unexpected host id

After that I am unable to launch the application either from start or visual studio. why this error occurs and how to fix that?

Comment: I had this error happening because my temporary key expired. Created a new key and it started working fine again. Not sure about store because for one of my app, the key expired 1 month back and it still works when you install from store

Comment: The temporary key is not expired,But when i reboot my system it starts working

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a known issue. The current workaround is to join the Windows Insider Program and get a Insider Preview version of Windows 10 which has this fixed. See [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/244961/the-operation-could-not-be-completed-because-an-un.html) for more information.

Comment: The issue occurs not only from VS, It occurs even in the store version of the app.

Comment: How do you know the error when you install the store version? Are you logging the error somewhere?

Comment: No from event viewer

Answer (score 0):

**- In order to solved this problem, you need to join the "Windows Insider Program" and to the join follow the steps.**

```
 -> Go to settings -> Windows Update -> Windows Insider Program -> Log in to your Microsoft account -> Choose your insider settings as "Beta Channel".
```

**- And you will get a Insider Preview version of Windows 11 which has this fixed.**

*Hope this helps*